# How can I continue to prompt for input, if my REGEX is not matched?

Tags: java, regex, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to get this loop to continue. So far, when input is not matched to my REGEX, "input not valid" gets displayed but loop won't continue. What am I missing here?

Apreciate your help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input;
    //some variables
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);


    boolean found = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("ask user for input");
        input = scn.next();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        try {
            matcher.find();
            //some Code
            found = true;
            scn.close();
        
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("input not valid."); //stuck here
            scn.next();
            continue;
        }
    } while (!found);

            // some more Code

}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Why would you not capture the result of `Matcher.find()`? What is "some code"? Why do you set found to true?

Comment: i set found to true to end the loop. //Some Code is just two lines that use the pattern Groups from input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

- `IllegalStateException` is not raised by the "not-match", but by the Scanner class, so why catch it?
- you are not doing anything with the result of `matcher.find()`, I think you want `found = matcher.find()`
- in case the input is not valid, you execute twice `scn.next();`

Moreover:

- you can simplify the initialization `boolean found = false;` with `boolean found;`
- `continue;` at the end of a loop is not necessary

Fixed code:

```
    boolean found;
    do {
        System.out.println("ask user for input");
        input = scn.next();
        found = pattern.matcher(input).find();
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("input not valid.");
        }
    } while (!found);
    scn.close();
```

Comment: That looks a lot more rational. It's not necessary to close a `Scanner` on stdin

Comment: Thx! that's a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like `scn.next()` after your "input not valid" line isn't doing anything, but it's going to wait for the user to input a string. That's why it looks like the loop isn't continuing: it's waiting for you to input a string because of that line. However, when you do input something, that input will just be thrown away. Removing that line seems like it will do the trick.

Comment: That's it! Thank's Sam Cousins! I thought it was necessary to clear the Scanner like that... Thank's for your quick reply man!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your loop the condition of your loop state is !found right once the do finished the while test !found a true is need for continue but you defined found as true so !found= false so the while stop. you should get found to return false till the loop is over

Answer (score 0):

Let's try keeping things simple.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;
        String value;
        do {
            System.out.println("ask user for input");
            value = scn.next();
            valid = pattern.matcher(value).matches();
            if (!valid) System.out.println("input not valid.");
        } while (!valid);

        System.out.printf("Valid input is %s", value);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
ask user for input
123-abc
input not valid.
ask user for input
qwerty58
Valid input is qwerty58
Process finished with exit code 0
```